# Vulnerabilities of IT system due to hardware?

Tags: hardware, data-leakage, backdoor

Is there any relation between specific hardware (like specific kind of CPU etc) or laptop manufacturing brands and the hacked environments run on? Can this be measured in any way like stolen data or get owned by sending any exploit to an owner of such a hardware?

My first thought - should be not since the OS system is the hub for exploits etc. I guess there is no way to run BIOS execution code from the layer of Windows OS or OS X, neither Linux (supposing exploit took control over our system)?

But what about hidden exploits built in by manufacturers? Has anyone in this field been caught red-handed? Should I avoid any particular manufacturer if privacy and security is my priority?

Comment: Are you only worried about laptop hardware? Are you aware of the numerous router backdoors that have been discovered? Do those matter to you?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "backdoor" when you are asking about *intential* vulnerabilities for the purposes of data exfiltration or external control. If you search for that term, you will be able to refine your research.

Comment: Thank you hint, that is real help. And for made me conscious about router point. So probably also hardware of my internet provider or hardware used by possible VPN matters.. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern CPUs often have layers that operate below the level of the operating system (eg system management mode in x86 processors) so if the firmware controlling that lower level is compromised then the OS can be attacked.  People with specific knowledge of the hardware design would have an advantage compromising such lower level modes.

Smart phones often have a baseband controller that can access the memory used by the Smart part of the smart phone.  An attack directly on this baseband controller would then allow the main OS to be compromised even if it was patched for all known flaws.